# ScrollRect does not correctly update the position when clamping the normalized position, after removing/deactivating a child element from the content

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

This is an issue that I had to resolve myself after finding no solutions for it.

The issue was that after removing a GameObject element from the ScrollRect's content, it would not clamp its normalized position until the user starts moving it again. This could lead to the ScrollRect showing empty space when it is showing the last elements and has deactivated the last element from the parent.

- The normalized position value was not updating until the user interacted with the ScrollRect content.
- Setting the normalized position manually, after deactivating an element, would not work as it was working on old values that have not been updated yet (see above for why).

Comment: hi Alex ... wait, are you using the AutoLayout systems?  So, vertical group and so on...??

Comment: Yes, in my particular problem it was the Horizontal Layout Group script, with a Content Fitter script, and its children had the Layout Element script.

Comment: Hmm, I've not seen the problem -- will have to think about that.  Good one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to

1. Force a Canvas update after detecting a child, in the ScrollRect's content, being removed.
2. Then Clamping the value, since the normalized position has been updated correctly.

Example code:

```
        if (isRemoving) {
            Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
            scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Clamp(scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition, 0f, 1f);
        }
```

Comment: As this is the first post I found on Google, I just wanted to say that Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases() is rather expensive as it rebuilds every rect transform on every canvas in the scene. Instead, use LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(ScrollRect.RectTransform). Passing in a specific rect transform will only recursively rebuild the layouts of that object and its children.

Answer (score 0):

Well, better late than never. I have the same problem in my old Unity 5.6x. So, I found that switching between movementType causes scrollrect to update if you wait for few frames. Use:

```
StartCoroutine(UpdateScrollRect());
IEnumerator UpdateScrollRect()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        ScrolRect.movementType = ScrollRect.MovementType.Elastic;
        ScrolRect.elasticity = 0f;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        ScrolRect.movementType = ScrollRect.MovementType.Clamped;
    }
```

Try also to play with number of frames skip, so it fits your situation.
Cheers!
-Pavel